# Complex power series in a disk of radius $1$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $ |t| < 1 $ and $\theta \in \mathbb R$. Find $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\cos(n \theta), \space  \sum_{n=0}^\infty nt^n\cos(n \theta)$$
For real values of $t$ this is fairly straightforward, by taking the real partsof $(te^{i\theta})^k $ and considering a geometric sum. What about complex values of $t$? Can this still be calculated explicitly? For the first one, I tried placing $t=re^{i\phi} $ with $|r|<1$ a real number. Then we would obtain:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(n\phi)\cos(n\theta) + i\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \sin(n\phi) \cos(n\theta)$$
And using trig identities:

$$\frac 1 2 \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n(\cos(n(\phi-\theta)) + \cos(n(\phi+\theta))) + i\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n(\sin(n(\phi-\theta)) + \sin(n(\phi + \theta))) \right)$$

And then using the formula for real values. I'm having trouble using this approach because it gets really hairy and almost impossible to backtrack in order to put it in terms of $t$ and $\theta$. For the second one, I'm guessing that differentiating may help, but I don't know for sure. Thanks for any hints or solutions.

Comment: You could write $\cos(n\theta)$ as $\frac12(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly efficient way to proceed.  Note that for $t\in \mathbb{C}$, with $t=re^{i\phi}$, where $r=|t|<1$ and $\phi=\arg(t)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\cos(n\theta)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n e^{in\phi} \cos(n\theta)\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n (e^{in(\phi+\theta)}+e^{in(\phi-\theta)})\\\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{1-re^{i(\phi+\theta)}}+\frac{1}{1-re^{i(\phi-\theta)}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1-re^{i\phi}\cos(\theta)}{1+r^2e^{i2\phi}-2re^{i\phi}\cos(\theta)}\\\\
&=\frac{1-t\cos(\theta)}{1+t^2-2t\cos(\theta)}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $|t|<1$!

---

To find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nt^n\cos(n\theta)$, we can differentiate $(1)$ and multiply by $t$.

The term-by-term differentiation is valid for $|t|<\rho$ for all $\rho<1$ owing to the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nt^n\cos(n\theta)$ for  $|t|<\rho$ (and also the convergence of the original series at least on point on the same disk).